# Android. Positioning of 3 blocks in the layout

Tags: android, layout

This image describes what I need to create:
[image]

This my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:gravity="left"
            />
       <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            />
</LinearLayout>
<!-- Now the block that has to be flexible -->
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="15dp" 
    android:gravity="center" >
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
</ImageView>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
<!-- -------------------------------- -->
    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="61dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>
</ImageButton>

<ImageButton
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  >
</ImageButton>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
</ImageButton>

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The block, that has to stretch contains in ImageView and TextView.
So my question is - how to make this middle block to be flexible but keep two other blocks, at the top and at the bottom to stay there on any screen height? The middle block will be stretching.

Answer (score 0):

For the top and bottom layouts:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content" // or a value un pixels (e.g 100dp)
```

and for the flexible layout:

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Note that you don't need relative layouts. Simply use Linear layout and they will stack up properly

Comment: @kabuko, it does not work. I did it, then inserted a photo that is considerably long and the bottom block went down under the screen :(

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a `LinearLayout`. Set its `orientation` to `vertical` and `layout_height` to `fill_parent`. Set the `layout_weight` of the middle section to some positive value like `1` and for the fixed pieces just use `wrap_content` or some `dp` value as appropriate.